# Rotate screen orientation on Web App Tizen [TV]

Tags: web, tizen, tizen-web-app, tizen-emulator, tizen-studio

I'm developing a Web Application on Tizen. My application was first developed on other platforms like iOS and Android.

Basically it starts on Landscape mode and plays remote content such as image, video or opens a web page. It has a menu inside the app to offer people the ability to change the screen orientation inside the app manually.
This approach is quite easy on iOS and Android but on Tizen seems it doesn't work that easy.

I'm following Tizen's official documentation which send's us to : https://w3c.github.io/screen-orientation/
But, can't make it work even though I followed steps written on the link above.

This is what I got when I try to rotate:

Trying with :

`screen.orientation.lock('portrait-primary')`

Error :

```
Promise {}
index.html:1 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The page needs to be fullscreen in order to call screen.orientation.lock().
```

P.S. The app is already in fullscreen. The error is not relevant.

Do you have any ideas ?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

For all to those who are still trying to achieve this:

After having a long discussion with Samsung, they claimed that supporting the TV orientation via code is not possible right now (Not sure if it's gonna be implemented in the future).
These restrictions come due to different operability of the hardware components on different orientation.

The only way to rotate your screen is to do it via Samsung's TV Settings so that it can prepare its hardware for the chosen orientation.

Answer (score 1):

There are a special Samsung TVs for Advertising market (Digital Signage series) that are ready to set the orientation of the screen.

I comercial Samsung TV sets Tizen is not able to rotate some kind of elements (as far I know the video object are one of the HTML elements that cannot be rotated)

I've developed some apps for Tizen and for one customer I tried to make a video wall but it was impossible due the firmware limitation of Tizen (it's a marketing strategy in order to avoid having hotel and digital signage capabilities in commercial TV sets)